# Wordpress custom header files for different pages?

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering if it is possible to call different headers like for the get_sidebar(‘newsidebar’)?
can I maybe call get_header('custom')? I want to make my header for the index different then all the other pages

Comment: Do you want to add different syntax.. or just style the headers different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi headers

Different header for different pages.

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
get_header('home');
elseif ( is_404() ) :
get_header('404');
else :
get_header();
endif;
?>
```

The file names for the home and 404 headers should be header-home.php and header-404.php respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, view the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header